# How to serve components outside of the build directory with gulp-serve

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

Using the [gulp-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-serve) plugin, I'm serving my application at root `bin/dev/`, my folder structure is as follows:

```
bower_components/
    angular/
bin/
  dev/
    scripts/
    content/
        css/
    index.html
```

The injected references to `bower_components/` in `index.html` look like the following:

`"../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"`

When running `gulp serve`, the components aren't included when navigating to the application, e.g. `"../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"` could not be found.

Here is my gulp task:

`gulp.task('serve', plugins.serve('bin/dev/'));`

How can I serve my application and include assets outside of the build directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opted to use the [gulp-webserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver) plugin instead.

I was able to serve files outside of the directory using the middleware option like so:

```
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    gulp.src('./bin/dev/')
        .pipe(plugins.webserver({
            middleware: [
                serveStatic(__dirname)
            ]
        }));
});
```

Where `__dirname` is the root at path `./`.

I could then simply inject my scripts into `index.html` using something like:

`"bower_components/angular/angular.js"`